# VBScript/HTA Countdown, every hour

Tags: javascript, vbscript, hta

I am trying to achieve something simple, but can't get my head around it.

I have no code currently but I'm trying to create in `VBScript` to use within `HTA` a countdown timer that runs until `XX:58` - so it ends on the start of the 58th minute of every hour, then it can restart to countdown until the next 58th minute of the hour after ... and so on.

Does anyone know how to achieve this so I can format it within the HTA?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I usually use JScript in my HTA's (made quite a few). Here's one possible solution (using JScript). You should be able to convert this to VBS, or simply use as is if needed:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
//Check for the 58th minute once every minute
var Minute = 60000;

//Create a count-down timer to run my function every minute
var CountDownTimer = setInterval(function(){

  //If this is NOT the 58th minute, do nothing
  if ((new Date()).getMinutes() < 58) return;

  //Your code here...
}, Minute);
</script>
```

Cheers!